# Faster UIImage - Base64 conversion

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, base64, decode

I am doing work where I have to encode and decode between `UIImage` and Base 64 string). This works great with smaller images, it takes less than 1 second to do the conversion forward and backward, but when I apply it to larger images it takes a long time, almost a minute.

Is there any other way to encode and decode `UIImage` objects to string to save them in SQLite database? Or if there is no other way to improve this, is there something else I can do to get this job done and I could get rid of the problem?

These are the extension methods I use to do the work:

```
extension String {
    var toUIImage: UIImage? {
        var img = self
        img = String(img.characters.map({ $0 == "\r" ? " " : $0 }))
        img = String(img.characters.map({ $0 == "\n" ? " " : $0 }))
        img = String(img.characters.map({ $0 == "\r\n" ? " " : $0 }))
        let dataDecoded:NSData? = NSData(base64EncodedString: img, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
        return UIImage(data: dataDecoded!)
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    var toString: String {
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
        let encoded =  data!.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
        var cadena = String(data: encoded, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        cadena = String(cadena.characters.map({ $0 == "\r" ? " " : $0 }))
        cadena = String(cadena.characters.map({ $0 == "\n" ? " " : $0 }))
        cadena = String(cadena.characters.map({ $0 == "\r\n" ? " " : $0 }))

        return cadena
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you calling map 3 times,  just call it once: `img = String(img.characters.map({ ["\r","\n"].contains($0) ? " " : $0 }))`  (\r\n is not a character)  I am not sure if this 100% works, but you want something to this effect

Comment: i had a problem where it said that it said that i had some white spaces in the string, and to get rid of it i did that.. at least i know that work, do you think that if i change the way you suggest, it would reduce the time in the conversion?

Comment: You are going  through your image 3 times... Of course by looking at it. I am guessing it is wrong anyway,  you are changing pixel data

Comment: actually it was the problem, now it works in les than a second for full size images

Comment: FWIW, if you want to remove the `\r` and `\n`, I'd use `filter`, not `map` (or `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`). But you don't have to remove these characters: In your first extension, `.IgnoreUnknownCharacters` removes them for you. And if you don't use `.Encoding64CharacterLineLength` (which adds the `\r` and `\n`) in your second extension, then you don't have anything to remove.

Answer (score 5):

With the `String` extension, you can just use `.IgnoreUnknownCharacters` and you don't have to do any replacement of `\r` and `\n` at all:

```
extension String {
    var imageFromBase64EncodedString: UIImage? {
        if let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: self, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters) {
            return UIImage(data: data)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Likewise, in your `UIImage` extension, don't use `.Encoding64CharacterLineLength`, which introduces the `\r` and `\n`, only to then remove them. If you don't use that option, there is no `\r` and `\n` to remove:

```
extension UIImage {
    var base64EncodedString: String? {
        if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self) {
            return data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

Two observations regarding SQLite:

1. If you're going to store image in database, just store the `NSData` SQLite database as blob and be done with it. That not only eliminates this "what do I do with `\r` and `\n` characters", but it completely eliminates the base64 encoding/decoding process entirely. It also makes the what you store in the database 25% smaller. It's a lot more efficient.
2. Even with that, SQLite is notoriously inefficient in storing large objects in database at all. If you want best performance, store images in the file system, and only store relative path references in your database. My rule of thumb is that if I'm dealing with thumbnail images, SQLite blobs are fine, but for anything larger, use the file system.

Comment: Ok, the thing that storing it as NSData is that i get the result in [JSON] using SwiftyJSON, and JSON isn't capable to store NSData objects. I guess i will do it like the second option because they are going to be huge images

Comment: If the JSON gives you base64 data, then convert it to `NSData` (with `IgnoreUnknownCharacters` option that Avt describes, if necessary). But don't manipulate the string. And don't perpetuate this base64 string, but rather immediately convert it to `NSData` and then save it (either as blob in SQLite or on the file system) as the underlying `NSData`.

Comment: And if at all possible, rework the API to stop sending huge images as JSON. It's an insanely inefficient way to transmit images. In every API I work on, we separate images from the rest of the API, either as a separate endpoint or by moving them into a multipart form that doesn't require base64 encoding. You don't always have this option if you don't control the server, but JSON is not the right tool for dealing with large images (or anything but very small images). Its even worse on the server-side because of the memory impact.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need 'map' code at all. Following code:

```
img = String(img.characters.map({ $0 == "\r" ? " " : $0 }))
img = String(img.characters.map({ $0 == "\n" ? " " : $0 }))
img = String(img.characters.map({ $0 == "\r\n" ? " " : $0 }))
```

is useless if you use `NSData(base64EncodedString:options:)` with `IgnoreUnknownCharacters` option. Check the [description](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDataBase64DecodingOptions):

> IgnoreUnknownCharacters
>
> Modify the decoding algorithm so that it
> ignores unknown non-Base-64 bytes, **including line ending characters**.